# create tree from linux directory stucture

Tags: java

I need to create a tree from a linux directory stucture. For example:

```
. 0
./file1.txt 1
./file2.txt 2
./site 3
./site/file3.txt 4
./site/ru 5
./site/ru/file4.txt 6
```

Each node is a directory or file(if it has no children) and has ID(>=0). The root ID is 0. Parent ID is always lower than child ID. I've created 2 classes:

```
class Node<T1, T2> {
    T1 key;
    T2 value;

    List<Node<T1, T2>> children;

    Node(T1 key, T2 value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        children = new ArrayList<Node<T1, T2>>();
    }

    public boolean isFile()
    {
        return children.size() == 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DirectoryTree<T1 extends Comparable<T1>, T2> 
{
   private Node<T1, T2> root = null;

   public DirectoryTree(T1 key, T2 value)
   {
       root = new Node<T1, T2>(key, value);
   }
}
```

How can I fill the tree?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550043/read-file-system-structure-from-java

Comment: Thank you! But I have string array on input, where each element format  is the same linux directory stucture format. It is abstract input data. This files and directories do not exist

Comment: Sorry, i suggest you to enhance question expliciting that you are reading an array in input and do not want to read data from file system